# How to play Audio using raw data in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio, playback, audioqueue

I have been working on Audio capture and playback, I am trying to play audio using a buffer. I will get buffer as character pointer I have to read from the buffer and play if anything is present in that buffer. I came to know about AudioQueue, I am not sure AudioQueue will be the correct way for my task. Can anyone done this before, Please suggest some ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AudioQueues are fine for playback and recording of LPCM audio data signals. You've a lot to learn about audio signals and CoreAudio APIs before you will understand how this all works (an audio signal and AudioQueue crash course is way too big for one SO answer).

Start with some AudioQueue examples and tutorials. Reserve a good amount of time.